# How do I solve FirebaseUiException: Code 10, message 10

Tags: android, firebaseui

I know that there have been a few posts linked to this issue, but I was unable to find one that solves my issue. Many posts have mentioned needing 3 keys in order to use Google login for Firebase, but for the past year, my personal project has done fine with just 1 key, the debug key. I have never generated an APK nor published to Google Play, hence I do not think that the other keys are necessary. All I want to do is to be able to log in to the application on my emulator using a gmail account. Normal email authentication works, as well as other firebase database and storage services, so I'm especially confused.

A couple weeks ago I renamed many of the directories in the project. I'm not sure if it is a coincidence or not, but checking the git logs, the authentication works before the renaming but does not after the renaming. This meant that I edited the google-services.json file, which is now different from from the one that I download from the firebase console. Could this be the reason? It's several commits and hours of work behind the current head though.

I have verified my fingerprint SHA1 on the firebase console with the one on Android Studio. They are identical. I'm not sure what else I need to do. Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you

Edit: I should also add that I saw a youtube video that just deleted the firebase project and restarted. That is a true nuclear option that I do not wish to do...

Comment: Sorry, I'm late to the party, but did you ever figure this out?